# Trying to send JSON requests, get java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters

Tags: android, json, post

I get this error when I try to button click.

```
11-05 22:12:30.797  31048-31048/applicatoin W/System.err﹕ java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=172.27.123.71
11-05 22:12:30.797  31048-31048/applicatoin W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.determineRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:591)
11-05 22:12:30.797  31048-31048/applicatoin W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:293)
11-05 22:12:30.797  31048-31048/applicatoin W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
11-05 22:12:30.797  31048-31048/applicatoin W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
11-05 22:12:30.797  31048-31048/applicatoin W/System.err﹕ at applicatoin.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:79)
11-05 22:12:30.797  31048-31048/applicatoin W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
11-05 22:12:30.797  31048-31048/applicatoin W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
11-05 22:12:30.797  31048-31048/applicatoin W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
11-05 22:12:30.797  31048-31048/applicatoin W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-05 22:12:30.797  31048-31048/applicatoin W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-05 22:12:30.797  31048-31048/applicatoin W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
11-05 22:12:30.797  31048-31048/applicatoin W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-05 22:12:30.797  31048-31048/applicatoin W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-05 22:12:30.797  31048-31048/applicatoin W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
11-05 22:12:30.797  31048-31048/applicatoin W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
11-05 22:12:30.797  31048-31048/applicatoin W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am trying to send a JSON  post request to a server.
Here is my code:

```
package applicatoin;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;


public class MainActivity extends Activity  {


    Button sendIPbutton; //Button for sending IP Address
    EditText mEdit; //Get info from what user enters in form
    //TextView mText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /*get reference to views*/
        sendIPbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendIP);
        mEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterIP);

        /*add click listener to Button "sendIPbutton"*/
        sendIPbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                //Add JSON Logic here

                String ip = (mEdit).getText().toString();
                String json = "{\"lights\": [{\"lightId\": 1, \"red\":242,\"green\":116,\"blue\":12, \"intensity\": 0.5}],\"propagate\": true}";


                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpContext httpContext = new BasicHttpContext();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(ip);

                try {

                    StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);
                    httpPost.setEntity(se);
                    httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "ms3/json");
                    httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "ms3/json");

                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, httpContext);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                    String jsonString = EntityUtils.toString(entity);


                } catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                mEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.enterIP); //get text from form?
            }
        });
      //  addListenerOnButton(); //Added for button to Send IP Address
    }

    public void sendJSONTest(View view){
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.sendIP:
                String ip = (mEdit).getText().toString();
                String json = "{\"lights\": [{\"lightId\": 1, \"red\":242,\"green\":116,\"blue\":12, \"intensity\": 0.5}],\"propagate\": true}";


                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpContext httpContext = new BasicHttpContext();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(ip);

                try {

                    StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);
                    httpPost.setEntity(se);
                    httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "ms3/json");
                    httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "ms3/json");

                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, httpContext);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                    String jsonString = EntityUtils.toString(entity);


                } catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                break;

        }
    }
    public void sendJSONTest(String ip) {
        String json = "{\"lights\": [{\"lightId\": 1, \"red\":242,\"green\":116,\"blue\":12, \"intensity\": 0.5}],\"propagate\": true}";


        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext httpContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(ip);

        try {

            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);
            httpPost.setEntity(se);
            httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "ms3/json");
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "ms3/json");

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, httpContext);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            String jsonString = EntityUtils.toString(entity);


        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I am not sure what the cause of the error is. The button does identify the text in the text field, but when we try to do the HTTPrequest, we get the system error. The JSON is in the correct format. The server doesn't even get a request.

Comment: seems like google.com is not working

Comment: 1) Don't make network requests on the UI thread. 2) Really don't make network requests on the UI thread ;). 3) Normally for JSON, Content-Type should be application/json. 4) Can you ping the server at the given IP address?

Answer (score 0):

```
Use Seprate classes For sending all json request i will show one single demo



package applicatoin;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;


public class MainActivity extends Activity  {


    Button sendIPbutton; //Button for sending IP Address
    EditText mEdit; //Get info from what user enters in form
    //TextView mText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /*get reference to views*/
        sendIPbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendIP);
        mEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterIP);

        /*add click listener to Button "sendIPbutton"*/
        sendIPbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                //Add JSON Logic here
new SendRequest().execute(); 



                mEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.enterIP); //get text from form?
            }
        });
      //  addListenerOnButton(); //Added for button to Send IP Address
    }

}

Class SendRequest extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

 String ip = (mEdit).getText().toString();
                String json = "{\"lights\": [{\"lightId\": 1, \"red\":242,\"green\":116,\"blue\":12, \"intensity\": 0.5}],\"propagate\": true}";


                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpContext httpContext = new BasicHttpContext();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(ip);

                try {

                    StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);
                    httpPost.setEntity(se);
                    httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "ms3/json");
                    httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "ms3/json");

                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, httpContext);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                    String jsonString = EntityUtils.toString(entity);


                } catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

}

}
```